# Javascript if statement in function overwriting global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Am attempting to create a static navigation panel which becomes absolute at the bottom before the footer when reaching the end of the page content.

As I am developing for wordpress the page could be of varying height so I have attempted to trigger the absolute positioning when the nav panel “collides” with the footer.

So far I have used this code I found here

```
 function collision($archive, $footer){

    var archivexPos = $archive.offset().left;
    var archiveyPos = $archive.offset().top;
    var archiveHeight = $archive.outerHeight(true);
    var archiveWidth = $archive.outerWidth(true);
    var archiveb = archiveyPos + archiveHeight;
    var archiver = archivexPos + archiveWidth;

    var footerxPos = $footer.offset().left;
    var footeryPos = $footer.offset().top;
    var footerHeight = $footer.outerHeight(true);
    var footerWidth = $footer.outerWidth(true);
    var footerb = footeryPos + footerHeight;
    var footerr = footerxPos + footerWidth;

    if (archiveb < footeryPos || archiveyPos > footerb || archiver < footerxPos || archivexPos > footer) return Boolean = false;
    return Boolean = true;
```

And used a global variable of Boolean to pass to this function

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

    var scrollmath = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
    var archiveValue = scrollmath + 48;
    var archiveBottom = archiveValue + 'px';

    console.log('collision boolean', Boolean)


    if (Boolean = false) {
        $('#archive').css('position', 'fixed');
        $('#archive').css('top', '48px');   
    } else {
        $('#archive').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('#archive').css('top', archiveBottom);    
    }
```

My problem is the if statement seems to be creating another Boolean variable? As when I comment it out I can see that the console reports the Boolean variable as expected. However when I leave it in and they collide this happens

[image: picture of console output]

Whats happened here?

Comment: `if (Boolean = false) {` you can't assign value but do a comparison.

Comment: no, your real Problem is, that you overwrite the constructor for the Boolean Type.

Answer (score 5):

The primary thing that's happening is that you're using `=` for comparison. JavaScript uses `==` (or `===`), not `=`. `=` is always *assignment*.

But when testing the value of a boolean, you don't want `==` or `!=` anyway, just use the boolean directly:

```
if (flag) {
    // It was true
} else {
    // It was false
}
```

Or if you're just testing for false:

```
if (!flag) {
   // flag was false
}
```

(Note that because JavaScript does type coercion, that will also work with variables containing values other than booleans: Any *truthy* value coerces to `true`, any *falsy* value coerces to `false`. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`; all other values are truthy.)

Separately: `Boolean` is not a good choice for a variable name, as it's part of the JavaScript standard library (a function).

Also, your current `collision` function does two things:

1. It sets `Boolean` to `true` or `false`
2. It *returns* the value it set

In general, all other things being equal, it's best if a function doesn't have side-effects like that. If the caller wants to set `Boolean` to the return value of the function, he/she can, there's no need for the function to do it — it's already *returning* the value.

And finally: Global variables are, in general something to avoid. The global namespace on browsers is *incredibly crowded* and it's easy to get conflicts (for instance, a global called `name` may well not work as expected, because there's already a `name` global [it's the name of the window]).

Comment: complete oversight. was aware of the equal to operand but clearly not aware enough, thanks

Answer (score 0):

no, your real Problem is, that you overwrite the constructor for the Boolean Type.

1st. stick to coding conventions: Only classes start with an uppercase-letter.

2nd. local vars have to be declared with the `var`-Keyword (or `let` for block-scoped vars, or `const`).
otherwise you reference a var from a surrounding scope; and in the end, the global scope.

3rd. the equal-sign:

`===` means typesafe comprison

```
3 === 3   //=> true
3 === '3' //=>false
```

`==` means simple comparison

```
3 == '3'  //=> also true now
```

`=` means assignment, not comparison

```
var foo = 3;
```

if it inside of some other code like

```
var bar = 42 + (foo = 3);
//it works basically like 
var bar = 42 + (function(){
    foo = 3;
    return 3; //NOT FOO!!! not even foo after the assignment
})();

//the same way, that this:
var bar = 42 + foo++;
//works basically like this:
var bar = 42 + (function(){
    var result = foo;
    foo = foo+1;
    return result;
})();
```